# Ionic with ui-router.stateHelper

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

Is it possiable to use ionic with [ui-router.stateHelper](https://github.com/marklagendijk/ui-router.stateHelper)

I want to use this for help me working with nested views:
the property `children` is what I'm looking for.
If its not possible, how can i do something similar, without defining each child state with name: `parent.child`?

after installing and import im getting the next error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '@' of undefined at updateView (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:62199:69)
at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:62194:9
at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21830:9)
at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21330:11)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:20721:13)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:20725:13)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:20725:13)
at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:20596:30)
at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14815:27
at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29026:28) <ion-nav-view class="view-container" nav-view-transition="ios">
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok This is working.. I had problem with the indjection.
this is the right way: (im using browserify)

npm install angular-ui-router.statehelper

then in the `package.json`
under `browser`:

```
"angular-ui-router-helper": "./node_modules/angular-ui-router.statehelper/statehelper.min.js"
```

and under `browserify-shim`

```
"browserify-shim": {
   "angular": "angular",
   "ionic": "ionic",
   "angular-ui-router-helper": {
       "exports": "angular.module('ui.router.stateHelper')"
    }
  },
```

and then in the index.js:

```
var rootModule = angular.module('AppName', ['ionic',require('angular-ui-router-helper').name]);
```

Then u can inject the `stateHelperProvider` to the config method :)